# Sharepoint 2010: Get the List's / Library's IRM properties

Tags: list, document-library, properties, irm

I have been struggling with something lately.

Does anybody know where I could  pragmatically find a list's IRM settings?

I am talking about these properties:

[image]

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look, and this is easier in 2013 than it is in 2010, but it is certainly possible to do:

http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2013/07/using-powershell-to-manage-sharepoint-information-rights-management-settings/

Comment: Do you happen to know how can I retrieve the "vti_irm_IrmPrint" property value of a list with Client Object Model as well? Thank you.

Comment: I do not, I don't get into CSOM much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with powershell.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://teamsite.vladdev.com
$list = $web.GetList("Shared%20Documents")
$list.InformationRightsManagementSettings
```

Comment: InformationRightsManagementSettings is only available in 2013.